# How to Restore Kontact from a Backup?

Tags: kubuntu, 19.04, kontact

I use Kontact a lot and have a full backup of all files from my previous OS version before I upgraded to 19.04.

How can I restore contact? I had quite a bit of to-do's in this section that I would like to retain. What files would I have to replace on the new OS with the ones from the backup?

[image: Kontact]

Comment: Crawl through the menu, probably you found something useful.

Comment: @Emmet If you're referring to the import menu, yes I saw it, but I'm not about to start looking blindly for a file. There are certain likely places to start, but it would be far more efficient to ask first. (Not to mention other people who might have a similar issue)